# how to stop md3_raid1 and md3_resync process which takes high load

Tags: linux, kill-process

how to stop md3_raid1 and md3_resync process which takes heavy load. can anyone please help me how to stop this process and may i know why this process in started,, now there are 100 plus visitor , i dont need downtime. please help me quick.

```
 2273 root      20   0     0    0    0 S 12.0  0.0 955:29.96 md3_raid1
 25092 root      25   5     0    0    0 D  2.7  0.0  12:48.39 md3_resync
 2723 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  1.3  0.0 112:56.99 kworker/4:1H
 17787 hi5       20   0  187m  10m 6448 S  1.0  0.0   0:00.03 php
 10867 mysql     20   0 4365m  33m 3936 S  0.7  0.1 845:43.44 mysqld
 1784 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   3:05.27 kworker/3:1
 8755 nobody    20   0 76172 5768 2020 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.20 httpd
 10214 nobody    20   0 76168 5768 2028 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.17 httpd
 13922 nobody    20   0 76160 5748 2016 S  0.3  0.0   0:00.16 httpd
 23481 named     20   0  659m  72m 2040 S  0.3  0.1 407:30.27 named
 28093 root      20   0  317m  11m  648 S  0.3  0.0 296:02.68 searchd
 1 root      20   0 19280  348  168 S  0.0  0.0   0:18.82 init
 2 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.85 kthreadd
 3 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   9:02.43 ksoftirqd/0
 5 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:0H
 7 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:21.96 migration/0
 8 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 rcu_bh
 9 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0 115:24.56 rcu_sched
 10 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   1:11.76 migration/1
 11 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  14:47.88 ksoftirqd/1
 13 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/1:0H
 14 root      RT   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:25.82 migration/2
 15 root      20   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  14:18.92 ksoftirqd/2
```

Comment: That does not look like heavy load to me . But you can limit the raid reconstruction speed by `echo max_speed_in_kb_per_sec > /proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max`. Try a very low speed, like, 1000.

Comment: thank you,, but may i know how to reduce it

Answer (score 2):

This is maintenance work that your system needs to do on your md3 array so you shouldn't stop it.

You could slow it down and reduce the  by changing the values of `dev.raid.speed_limit_min`, `dev.raid.speed_limit_max` with [sysctl(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sysctl). The default values are though usually the defults are sensible.

You can see how much work is left to do by looking at the /proc/mdstat file.

To find out what's causing this you will need to review your logs for relevant information.